# Emgu Cv Motion Detection

Tags: emgucv

I'm working on hand detection using EmguCv. I have successfully detected the skin color object in live video feed. With in that skin detected object I want to track the moving hand only. Please someone tell me how to achieve this without degrading the performance. A code or step by step procedure will be helpful.

Is there any best reference ebook on EmguCv for learning or any other material with code snipets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you actually need to perform a number of steps to  do it.

1) you need to find the hand , the best way to figure that out will be to use `HarrCascades`,
you can find more about it here: http://www.360doc.com/content/11/1220/16/5087210_173660914.shtml

2)Then you need to use absolute subtraction between the `current frame` and the `previous frame` to find out the moving part in the video. 
for absolute subtraction you can check this [link out.](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/CompareImages_-_Difference)

Answer (score 0):

After detecting the hand you can use Mean Shift Tracking Algorithm to track the hand.There is a good implementation in Accord.NET and an example that you can use for learning how to use it. About Viola-Jones algorithm m there is a HandCascade.xml file from a guy Nikolas Markou , but when I tried it , the performance wasn't good at all and there are similare complaints from other people using that Haar Cascade.

Comment: Please, try to read this http://stackoverflow.com/about, to get more understanding about questions/answers here on SO. Your contribution is not answering the question. It is more a comment, which you can add once you'll increase your reputation: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation

Answer (score 0):

About the reference book of EmguCv, to my best knowledge, there is only one book so far:

Emgu CV Essentials

[http://www.amazon.com/Emgu-CV-Essentials-Shin-Shi-ebook/dp/B00GOMTTHI](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GOMTTHI)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: I just know about the reference book which Micro Ice asked, not about motion detection part. I post it in case someone might find it useful. But I appreciate your point.